# Confirmation message not displaying on javascript contact form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have used emailJS.com to create a contact form. The form is working with the code below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      emailjs.sendForm('gmail2', 'filtrastop', this);
      document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
    });

    document.getElementById('form2').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      emailjs.sendForm('gmail2', 'filtrastop', this);
      document.getElementById('form2').reset();
    });
  }

</script>
```

I am trying to add a confirmation/error message **that is displayed to the user** when the form is submitted. After reading the docs (https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/send-form/)

My code now looks like this, but I'm not seeing any messages? Please help!

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      emailjs.sendForm('gmail2', 'filtrastop', this).then(function (response) {
        console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
      }, function (error) {
        console.log('FAILED...', error);
      });
      document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
    });

    document.getElementById('form2').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
    }, function (error) {
      console.log('FAILED...', error);
    });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not seeing anything in the browser console?  Or are you talking about form2 not working properly?  I noticed that form2 you added in that console code differently than you did with contact-form.  It looks like you added in the console.log to the addEventListener of form2 instead of the emailjs.sendForm that was in your code for form2 which is what the link you provided specifies.

Comment: Hi Doug, I was hoping the code would display a message to the user so they know the message has been sent. Have i got something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your 'form2' addEventListener(). Without calling emailjs.send() your directly use response object you'll get undefined error.You can use first emailjs.send() then use response object. Please check my code.

I have unable to comment so I add my code. Please give your all config key details and run and check my code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2.4.0/dist/email.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        emailjs.init("YOUR_USER_ID");
    })();

    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var templateParams = {
                to_name: 'prabhat',
                from_name: 'Tapas',
                message_html: 'Please Find out the attached file'
            };

            emailjs.send('serviceID', 'templateID', templateParams)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.status == 200 && response.text == 'OK')
                        alert('Your message has been sent Successfully..!!!');
                    else
                        alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!!!');
                }, function (error) {
                    alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!!!');
                });
            document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
        });

        document.getElementById('form2').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var templateParams = {
                to_name: 'prabhat',
                from_name: 'Padhy',
                message_html: 'Please Find out the attached file'
            };

            emailjs.send('serviceID', 'templateID', templateParams)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.status == 200 && response.text == 'OK')
                        alert('Your message has been sent Successfully..!!!');
                    else
                        alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!!!');
                }, function (error) {
                    alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!!!');
                });
            document.getElementById('form2').reset();
        });
    }
</script>


<form id="contact-form">
    <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Prabhat, Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately its still not displaying either a confirmation or error message.

Comment: Hi icm,did you change your code? and Please check in console in inspect it'll display like (SUCCESS! 200 OK).

Comment: Are you sure your first code is working fine. If you click then are you able to get mail?

Comment: Yes correct. Just to confirm, the form was working before. Iim trying to display a message for the user with the code i added? E.g. Your message has been sent. Thanks

Comment: Then instead of console you can use alert for showing message to user if your satatus is (SUCCESS! 200 OK).

Comment: Hi Prabhat, Yes this is what was the purpose of my question. I thought adding the code i used would display this message to the uder. Maybe i asked the wrong question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202126/discussion-between-prabhat-and-icm).

Answer (score 1):

Prabhat was very helpful taking through chat. We managed to get it working exactly as required!

Below is the updated version of the working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
emailjs.init("user_##########");
})();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
emailjs.sendForm('gmail2', 'filtrastop', this).then(function (response) {
if (response.status == 200 && response.text == 'OK')
alert('Your message has been sent Successfully..!!!');
else
alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!');
}, function (error) {
alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!!!');
});
document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
});

document.getElementById('form2').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
emailjs.sendForm('gmail2', 'filtrastop', this).then(function (response) {
if (response.status == 200 && response.text == 'OK')
alert('Your message has been sent Successfully..!!!');
else
alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!');
}, function (error) {
alert('Sorry there was a problem. Please try again...!!!');
});
document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you..So Much..ICM.